# how to fix the def to return the links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I located some links on a web site with beautifullSoup and need to return them in a list(or txt file) to use them later on.

It's to get some text from the links on the sites they lead to. I tried to make a `def` to return the links but I'm not smart enough to get the def working.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link["href"])
```

I get a list of links from the code above and could make it write into a text file (by myself) and make a new python script but I would rather prefer to "return" it to continue the script and by the way learn something.
i came up with this but doesnt work:

```
def linkgetter(soup):
    for link in soup.find('a', href=True):
    return soup
```

it prints out the whole site's html code and doesn't filter the links.

Comment: In general, you want to return a list of links extracted by the `for` loop, not the `soup` that represents the entire page object from which you extract the links. This is what [a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) does.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_links(soup):
    return [link["href"] for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

def parse_links(url):
    links = []
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    return links

print parse_links("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826906/how-to-fix-the-def-to-return-the-links#57826972")
```

If you would like to get the links starting with http://, you can use:

```
soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})
```

Comment: ok, thx a lot. the urllib2 should be replaceble with the urllib3 and re should be corresponding to requests?

Comment: You can replace urllib2 with urllib3. I've included re for  regular expression matching operations, just in case if you are interested in parsing links starting with http://.